# How can I get data for multiple symbols with one alphavantage requests

Tags: python, api, http, finance, alpha-vantage

My code works fine, but alphavantage free api is limited to 500 requests per day, so getting datas for 500 symbols would take 10 days (because alphavantage chucked every file in 24 parts).
How can I get with one requests datas for multiple symbols?

Here is my code:

```
def getdata(tickers, fetta):
    for i in range(1,51):
        for a in range(len(fetta)):
            url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol='+tickers[i]+'&interval=1min&slice='+fetta[a]+'&apikey=XXX'
            webbrowser.open(url)


            time.sleep(12.0)
    
tickers = ['A', 'AAP', 'ABBV', 'ABC', 'ABMD', 'ABT', 'ACN', 'ADM', 'AEE', 'AEP', 'AES', 'AFL', 'AIG', 'AIV', 'AIZ', 'AJG', 'AKAM', 'ALB', 'ALK', 'ALL', 'ALLE', 'AMCR', 'AME', 'AMP', 'AMT', 'ANET', 'ANSS', 'ANTM', 'AON', 'AOS', 'APA', 'APD', 'APH', 'APTV', 'ARE', 'ATO', 'AVB', 'AVY', 'AWK', 'AXP', 'AZO', 'BA', 'BAC', 'BAX', 'BBY', 'BDX', 'BEN', 'BIO', 'BK', 'BKNG', 'BKR', 'BLK', 'BLL', 'BMY', 'BR', 'BSX', 'BWA', 'BXP', 'CAG', 'CAH', 'CARR', 'CAT', 'CB', 'CBOE', 'CBRE', 'CCI', 'CCL', 'CDW', 'CE', 'CF', 'CFG', 'CHD', 'CHRW', 'CI', 'CINF', 'CL', 'CLX', 'CMA', 'CME', 'CMG', 'CMI', 'CMS', 'CNC', 'CNP', 'COF', 'COG', 'COO', 'COP', 'COTY', 'CPB', 'CPRT', 'CRM', 'D', 'DHI', 'DHR', 'DIS', 'DISCA', 'DISCK', 'DISH', 'DLR', 'DOV', 'DOW', 'DPZ', 
    'DRE', 'DRI', 'DTE', 'DUK', 'DVA', 'DVN', 'DXC', 'DXCM', 'ECL', 'ED', 'EFX', 'EIX', 'EL', 'EMN', 'EMR', 'EOG', 'EQIX', 'EQR', 'ES', 'ESS', 'ETFC', 'ETN', 'ETR', 'EVRG', 'EW', 'EXC', 'EXPD', 'EXR', 'F', 'FANG', 'FBHS', 'FCX', 'FDX', 'FE', 'FFIV', 'FIS', 'FITB', 'FLIR', 'FLS', 'FLT', 'FMC', 'FRC', 'FRT', 'FTI', 'FTNT', 'FTV', 'GD', 'GE', 'GIS', 'GL', 'GLW', 'GM', 'GPC', 'GPN', 'GPS', 'GRMN', 'GS', 'GWW', 'HAL', 'HBAN', 'HBI', 'HCA', 'HD', 'HES', 'HFC', 'HIG', 'HII', 'HLT', 'HOLX', 'HON', 'HPE', 'HPQ', 'HRB', 'HRL', 'HST', 'HSY', 'HUM', 'HWM', 'IBM', 'ICE', 'IEX', 'IFF', 'INFO', 'IP', 'IPG', 'IPGP', 'IQV', 'IR', 'IRM', 'IT', 'ITW', 'IVZ', 'J', 'JCI', 'JKHY', 'JNJ', 'JNPR', 'JPM', 'K', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'KIM', 'KMB', 'KMI', 'KMX', 'KO', 'KR', 'KSS', 'KSU', 'L', 'LB', 'LDOS', 'LEG', 'LEN', 'LH', 'LHX', 'LIN', 'LKQ', 'LLY', 'LMT', 'LNC', 'LNT', 'LOW', 'LUV', 'LVS', 'LW', 'LYB', 'LYV', 'MA', 'MAA', 'MAS', 'MCD', 'MCK', 'MCO', 'MDT', 'MET', 'MGM', 'MHK', 'MKC', 'MKTX', 'MLM', 'MMC', 'MMM', 'MO', 'MOS', 'MPC', 'MRK', 'MRO', 'MS', 'MSCI', 'MSI', 'MTB', 'MTD', 'NBL', 'NCLH', 'NDAQ', 'NEE', 'NEM', 'NI', 'NKE', 'NLOK', 'NLSN', 'NOC', 'NOV', 'NOW', 'NRG', 'NSC', 'NTRS', 'NUE', 'NVR', 'NWL', 'NWS', 'NWSA', 'O', 'ODFL', 'OKE', 'OMC', 'ORCL', 'OTIS', 'OXY', 'PAYC', 'PBCT', 'PEAK', 'PEG', 'PFE', 'PFG', 'PG', 'PGR', 'PH', 'PHM', 'PKG', 'PKI', 'PLD', 'PM', 'PNC', 'PNR', 'PNW', 'PPG', 'PPL', 'PRGO', 'PRU', 'PSA', 'PSX', 'PVH', 'PWR', 'PXD', 'QRVO', 'RCL', 'RE', 'REG', 'RF', 'RHI', 'RJF', 'RL', 'RMD', 'ROK', 'ROL', 'ROP', 'RSG', 'RTX', 'SBAC', 'SCHW', 'SEE', 'SHW', 'SIVB', 'SJM', 'SLB', 'SLG', 'SNA', 'SO', 'SPG', 'SPGI', 'SRE', 'STE', 'STT', 'STX', 'STZ', 'SWK', 'SYF', 'SYK', 'SYY', 'T', 'TAP', 'TDG', 'TDY', 'TEL', 'TFC', 'TFX', 'TGT', 'TIF', 'TJX', 'TMO', 'TPR', 'TROW', 'TRV', 'TSCO', 'TSN', 'TT', 'TWTR', 'TXT', 'TYL', 'UA', 'UAA', 'UDR', 'UHS', 'UNH', 'UNM', 'UNP', 'UPS', 'URI', 'USB', 'V', 'VAR', 'VFC', 'VIAC', 'VLO', 'VMC', 'VNO', 'VTR', 'VZ', 'WAB', 'WAT', 'WEC', 'WELL', 'WFC', 'WHR', 'WM', 'WMB', 'WMT', 'WRB', 'WRK', 'WST', 'WU', 'WY', 'XOM', 'XRAY', 'XRX', 'XYL', 'YUM', 'ZBH', 'ZBRA', 'ZION', 'ZTS']
    
fetta = ['year1month1', 'year1month2', 'year1month3', 'year1month4', 'year1month5', 'year1month6',
            'year1month7', 'year1month8', 'year1month9', 'year1month10']
    
getdata(tickers, fetta)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they support such a request at this point in time. There used to be an endpoint function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES and this gave data about multiple tickers for the same day, but they discontinued it a while ago.